# Mocking a Static TextView in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, powermockito

I am testing a method in another class which contains static textview from Main Activity. I have completed the unit test without it. It is working without it but not working when I add static textview. Here is code which is I am testing that contains a static Textview from MainActivity:

```
public void Methodtobetested() {
MainActivity.location.setTextColor(Color.GREEN); //location is static textview

}
```

Should I mock Mainactivity in the testing class then I should stub or How should I proceed with it?

Comment: You are probably better off  by fixing MainActivity code. Static TextView is most probably a bad idea.

Comment: Okay Thanks. What if I have textview instead of static text view should I mock it somehow then?

Comment: Do not make your textview public, instead add public methods in your mainactivity. These are easy to mock.

Comment: Thank you very much you solved my problem :)